# Temperature of electric burners

Tags: equipment, electric-stoves

I have an electric stove with two sizes of burners.  What is the general temperature in Fahrenheit when the small burners are on medium?

Comment: This is an almost impossible question to ask. I suggest buying an inexpensive infrared thermometer to measure the temperature in situation. This would not be a standardized temperature, even from model to model.

Comment: Temperature rises until energy input equals energy loss (balance). So burner temperature will be lower when an object (a pan) conducts energy away.